# How I can find function in shared object files using objdump and bash functions in linux?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shared-libraries, objdump

I've got a folder in linux, which is contained several shared object files (*.so). How I can find function in shared object files using objdump and bash functions in linux?

For instance, the following example is found me function `func1` in mylib.so:

```
objdump -d mylib.so | grep func1
```

But i want to find `func1` in folder which is contained shared object files. I don't know bash language and how to combinate linux terminal commands.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`nm` is simpler than `objdump`, for this task.
`nm -A *.so | grep func` should work. The `-A` flag tells `nm` to print the file name.

Comment: You need the `-D` option as well to actually look in the list of exported symbols.

Comment: @jørgensen, it isn't clear from the question whether he wants an exported function. Maybe he wants to know what library he needs to rebuild after changing a function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use also use,

```
find <path> -name "*.so" -exec nm {} \; | grep func1
```

Comment: `grep func1 nm {}`?? Do you mean `nm {} | grep func1`?

Comment: You would run nm | grep func1, the execution is from left to right if you are using it without exec. But with exec the execution is from right to left and {} specifies the input from the find command, so the above command means 'run the grep on the result of the nm for all the files from find'.

Comment: I tried your line - it just doesn't work. It just runs `grep func1 nm xxx.so` per file, which searches for `func1` in a file called "nm" and in the binary (without running nm).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not notice that too closely last time. I have edited my answer.